# Android listView center position in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-relativelayout

i have an RelativeLayout and also have listview inside this RelativeLayout. I want my listview would be center position. listivew would start in screen center
this is a my xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ff0000" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/menu_content_menulist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:divider="@null" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try something like `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"`

Comment: why do you have two `RelativeLayout`. This code would probably result in `Error in an XML file: aborting build`. Anyway to answer your question there are properties in relativelayout such as centerInParent, Gravity, Gravity_layout, etc.

Comment: @PedroHawk nothink changed.i added you code

Comment: `layout_graivty` doesn't work for `RelativeLayout`. [See the docs for available properties](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

Comment: @codeMagic you're right. my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following in your `ListView` attributes:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Comment: this is not solution.can you show me all xml code? this is  not solution

Comment: It is a solution. I told you exactly what to do. Add that single attribute to the ones within your `ListView`. Try it before you say it is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

FIrst of all you only need one RelativeLayout as parent (If you have no other elements in this xml only ListView would be enough as well). 
Below are couple of solutions you can use any of them that suits your requirements

**Method 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/menu_content_menulist"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    <!-- Used centerInParent property to place the view in Centre of screen -->
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Method 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
<!-- set the gravity of parent element to center which is applied to its child elements -->
android:gravity="center" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/menu_content_menulist"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

in your main RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/menu_content_menulist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:divider="@null" >
</ListView>
```